# problems displaying page, deleting contents and repopulating - could this be multiple binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have a mobile app.

It consists of 2 screens.  The first is for capturing user
credentials and the 2nd is for displaying data.

The idea is to collect the credentials on screen 1.

Then make an ajax call with the credentials to get data and present it on
screen 2 as a series of links.

Then allow the user to touch a link on screen 2.  This will return the link data to the javascript and pass it to the ajax call and get more data - THEN delete all the data on screen 2 and repopulate it with the new data.

First thing I want to find out:  is showing a page with mobile.changePage(), populating it, deleting the contents and then repopulating it (without another call to mobile.changePage()) a reasonable thing to do?

I'm having a problem and I think its related to how I'm using onclick in the `<a>`

Each time I display the most recently received data, I want to display it in an `<a>`.  I write each onclick to call the getData routine passing it information to determine the next ajax AND whatever is being displayed in the `<a>`.  The only way I could figure out to access that was in onclick.

Is there a better way?

I'm able to display the results of the first ajax call just fine.  But things get weird with the 2nd, 3rd etc.

Sometimes I'll touch a link and I'll progress thru the screens as I expect.

Sometimes I'll touch an `<a>` on the 1st result screen, the 2nd result screen will display and then (without me selecting data from the 2nd screen) the 3rd screen will display.

I've looked at the logs and the getData() routine is being executed.

What could be causing this?  Am I somehow not destroying all the `<a>` properly?  Am I using onclick in a fashion its not designed for?  Should I be using buttons styled to look like links instead of `<a>`

Here's my code:

```
"use strict";

var app = {

    onDeviceReady: function() {

        $('#startButton').click(function(){
             app.getDeptsForUser();
    });

    },
    getDeptsForUser: function(){

        var parms = new Object();
        parms.userName = assignedUser;
        app.getData(JSON.stringify(parms),"ENDPOINT1", "Departments");

        $.mobile.changePage("#index", { transition: 'slide' });

    },
    getData: function(paramStr, endpoint, displayHeader){

    var paramStrObj = JSON.parse(paramStr);
    var serverName = server + ":" + port;
    var encoded = Base64().encode(paramStrObj.userName + ':' + pass);
    var authType =  'Basic ' + encoded;

    var option = endpoint+"?action=start&params=" + paramStr;
    var URL = serverName + "/rest/bpm/wle/v1/service/"+option;

    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        jsonp: "callback",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authType);
        },
        success: function (result) {

        console.log("MobileMockUp getData() ajax success result="+JSON.stringify(result));
        if (endpoint === "ENDPOINT1"){
            app.displayData(paramStr, endpoint,"Departments", result.data.data.depts.items);
        }
        else if (endpoint === "ENDPOINT2"){
            app.displayData(paramStr, endpoint,displayHeader, result.data.data.checklists.items);
        }
        else if (endpoint === "ENDPOINT3"){
            app.displayData(paramStr, endpoint,displayHeader, result.data.data.checks.items);
        }

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Unable to retrieve '+displayHeader);
        },
     });
    },
    displayData: function(currParms,currEndPt, headerText, list){

    var nextEndpt;
        var nextHeaderText;
    var currParmsObj = JSON.parse(currParms);

    if (currEndPt === "MD@getDeptsForUser"){
        nextEndpt = "MD@getCheckLists";
        nextHeaderText = "Check Lists";
    }
    else if (currEndPt === "MD@getCheckLists"){
        nextEndpt = "MD@getChecks";
    }

    var htmlListString="";
    var parmObj;
    var newLink;

    $('#headerText').text(headerText);


    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){

        parmObj = new Object();
        if (currEndPt === "ENDPOINT1"){
          parmObj.userName=currParmsObj.userName;
          parmObj.dept=list[i];
        }
        else if (currEndPt === "ENDPOINT2"){
          parmObj.userName=currParmsObj.userName;
          parmObj.dept=currParmsObj.dept;
          parmObj.checklist=list[i];    
        }
        else if (currEndPt === "ENDPOINT3"){
        nextHeaderText = list[i];
        }

        var str = JSON.stringify(parmObj);
        str = str.toString().replace(/"/g, '\\"');

        newLink = "<a style='background:#ffffff;padding-top:5%;border-top: thin solid black; display:block;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;color:#000000;text-decoration: none;'  href='#' onclick='app.getData(\""+str+"\",\""+nextEndpt+"\",\""+nextHeaderText+"\")'><pre>" + list[i] + "     </pre></a><br>";

        htmlListString=htmlListString+newLink;

    }

    $('#taskListUL').empty();
    $('#taskListUL').append(htmlListString);
 }
```

};

Could this be multiple binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out it was multiple bindings